# return statements not working correctly when building a javadoc in a maven project (using restdoclet)

Tags: maven, javadoc

Im working on the restyling of an API document. We are using maven with restdoclet. The generic code we're using for an API description looks like this:

```
/**
 * <name>API name</name>
 * <description>API description</description>
 * <type>API type</type>
 * <versions>
 *  <version>
 *   <number>1</number>
 *   <response>{"success":true}</response>
 *  </version>
 * </versions>
 * 
 * @param request
 * @param version API version
 * @param param1 first parameter
 * @param param2 (optional) second parameter
 * @return
 */
```

The javadoc is automatically generated. The problem is that sometimes the content of the < response > (which is basically what the api returns) is displayed correctly (colors, indentation), in other cases it just doesn't display at all.

The old document had some APIs with wrong responses so I thought that was what was causing it. 
With some calls worked like a charm, but there are still some APIs that aren't getting the proper format or are just getting a part of the response (this happens just in some cases and when the call returns an array of values).

What confuses me is that I see no difference in the code, but some response are built correctly and some aren't.
I've tried to look into some xsl config files (where there are the build rules for other tags such as < name >, < type >, < version >). This is what I think it's supposed to handle the < response >:

```
<div class="{substring-after(../../../uri/uri, '/')}-response-{number}">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
   var json = <xsl:value-of select="response"/>;
   JSONFormatter.format(json, {
    'collapse': false,
    'appendTo': '.<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(../../../uri/uri,'/')"/>-response-<xsl:value-of select="number"/>',
    'list_id': 'json-<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(../../../uri/uri,'/')"/>-<xsl:value-of select="number"/>'
   });
  });
 </script>
</div>
```

so it might e related to JSONFormatter but i can't understand where it fails, and why on just some.

Any idea?